# HiddenService cannot set my own Domain (Privatkey)

Tags: onion-services, tor-install, debian, blocked-services, server-administration

I have set up a hidden service.
The domain at / var / lib / tor / hidden_service is very long.

**example.**
*tbwvbpnuwntiuofn4e3vwpsldmuxs3l5zv4vy3dbfpv5psmkrycmqid.onion* V3 how can i set v2 or replace the domain with my bruted.

I would like to insert my private key to use my domain (bruted).

The private key file cannot be overwritten, however, because the file is replaced each time tor "service tor restart" is replace?

The content of the private key is also encrypted
Example:
J) (§ $) * "" § (§ $ # § $ 78 /
§/$(§=§)$=)=§"§'§*$"§'$*§ $ 78 /

**I did it according to this guide**
https://famicoman.com/2018/01/05/configuring-a-tor-hidden-service/

It also works but I want to use my private keys.
Can someone help me? :( I've been looking for 8 hours. Google doesn't help me there.
I tried PHP 7.0 and PHP 7.4

regards.

Comment: Just so you're aware, V2 onion services are being deprecated and will be removed in around 15 months: https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2020-June/014365.html. For your problem, did you set `HiddenServiceVersion 2` in your torrc file?

Comment: No, I didn't. I think that's the solution. Thank you very much will test it tomorrow :) <3